# How can I convert from Double Precision to Bigint with PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, type-conversion

I need to convert a value of Double Precision to Bigint with PostgreSQL. How can I do that?

I have tried with `to_bigint(myvalue)` but that function didn't exist.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

There are two ways to typecast in Postgres:

You either do it the SQL standard way:

```
select cast(3.141593 as bigint);
```

or you could use the Postgres-specific cast operator: `::`

```
select (3.141593 :: bigint);
```

You might also want to consider the various [rounding functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-math.html).

Comment: @eevar Just a note from the docs, the rounding functions return type is "same as input," so if the type is important, casts are required.

Comment: Looks like `CAST` actually does rounding

Comment: Is there a doc which function is applied when `SELECT 4.7::int`?